# Config file for Neo4j Docker Image

Tags: macos, docker, neo4j

I installed neo4j-3.0 as a docker image in Mac OSX. Where can I locate the config file for neo4j ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They have a dedicated [section](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/docker/#docker-neo4j-configuration) on their page for that ...

There are 3 ways: via environment variables, mounting a `/conf` volume and building a new image

The `/conf` volume is probably the way the OP wants:

> To make arbitrary modifications to the Neo4j configuration, provide
>   the container with a /conf volume.
>
> ```
> docker run \
>     --detach \
>     --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
>     --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data \
>     --volume=$HOME/neo4j/logs:/logs \
>     --volume=$HOME/neo4j/conf:/conf \
>     neo4j:3.1
> ```
>
> Any configuration files in the /conf volume will override files
>   provided by the image. This includes values that may have been set in
>   response to environment variables passed to the container by Docker.
>   So if you want to change one value in a file you must ensure that the
>   rest of the file is complete and correct.
>
> To dump an initial set of configuration files, run the image with the
>   dump-config command.
>
> ```
> docker run --rm\
>     --volume=$HOME/neo4j/conf:/conf \
>     neo4j:3.1 dump-config
> ```

Comment: This link is broke... please include the detail in the post (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262038/how-to-flag-dead-links)

Comment: Why do we add --rm in the dump-config way of doing it?

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you for fully elaborating on the information regarding config files and docker images!