# Neo4j - How to access bolt from a secure connection using Docker image?

Tags: angular, docker, neo4j, google-kubernetes-engine

New to Docker. So I have managed to deploy the official Neo4j EE Docker image to Google Container Engine, and when running my Angular application from localhost everything is fine (because it's not coming from a secure connection).

However, when I deploy the app to Firebase, then the app makes all calls to the DB/Docker container from a secure connection, which results in the following error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://luminate-testing-24112016.firebaseapp.com/dashboard'
was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint
'ws://35.196.251.244:7687/'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available
over WSS.
```

Note that this happens regardless of whether the Docker image is deployed to GKE or AWS.

Here are my yaml files:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: neo4j
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  - 0.0.0.0/0
  ports:
  - name: browser
    port: 7474
    protocol: TCP
  - name: bolt
    port: 7687
    protocol: TCP
  - name: https
    port: 7473
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: neo4j

apiVersion: "apps/v1beta1"
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: neo4j
spec:
  serviceName: neo4j
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: neo4j
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: neo4j
        image: luminateqr/neo4j-with-apoc:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - name: browser
          containerPort: 7474
        - name: bolt
          containerPort: 7687
        - name: https
          containerPort: 7473
        volumeMounts:
        - name: neo4j-data
          mountPath: /data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: neo4j-data
      annotations:
        volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: slow
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 50Gi

kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: slow
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
  zone: us-east1-c
```

There are a few questions and answers floating around that seem similar, but I can't figure out which ones apply and which ones don't. I understand that setting up a websocket over TLS has something to do with it, but there is no consistent and/or explicit answer on how to do this (which seems odd as this is probably a common scenario)

Comment: I assume you are trying to directly access the DB through your code ?

Comment: Yep. Although I did just wonder if putting an ssl certificate on the GKE instance might solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set this parameter in your neo4j.conf

```
dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=REQUIRED
```

In case of docker you have the options described here: [Config file for Neo4j Docker Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017768/config-file-for-neo4j-docker-image)

Comment: How do you do this in the official docker container?

Comment: I usually do the following:
I mount a directory, where I have a shell script.
In docker-compose.yml I have something like this:
environment:
    NEO4J_AUTH: "none"
    EXTENSION_SCRIPT: /xx/extra_conf.sh
 
And in my script I have something like this:
echo "dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=REQUIRED" >> conf/neo4j.conf

Comment: Thank you. Let me try all this tomorrow when I get to a terminal.

Comment: Ok, I at least figured out how to get into the running pod via the cloud shell: kubectl exec -it neo4j-0 -- /bin/bash

Comment: so i've actually just gone in and changed the line in neo4j.conf now that I know where it is. still getting same error

Comment: Did you restart the database? If you did, then I have no other idea. The shell solution is not the best, since it does not preserve the config, and with docker compose you will have the original conf file. That is why I linked above the solutions for that.
This tls_level and ssl policy are the things you can configure related neo4j database bolt connection security.

Comment: finally worked it out with someone's help, thank you!